# Select aggregation root where all aggregates satisfy a particular condition

Tags: mysql, sql

Consider the following situation,

[image: Order and -item]

```
http://yuml.me/diagram/scruffy;/class/edit/[Order]++-1..*>[OrderItem]
```

Now I want to fetch the Order items where *all* of their line OrderItems have, let's say, an `itemSum > 100` or so. Or for a more sense making use case maybe, consider `OrderItem` having a property `shipsFree` and I want to select the orders where *every* OrderItem ships free.

If I just `(LEFT) JOIN` them, the Order would appear if one single OrderItem matches the condition, but not *all* of them.

Thanks for your ideas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Case 1:

```
select
*
from
order o 
inner join orderItem oi on o.id = oi.orderId
group by o.id
having sum(items) > 100
```

Case 2:

```
select
*
from
order o 
inner join orderItem oi on o.id = oi.orderId
group by o.id
having sum(property = 'shipsFree') = count(*)
```

Comment: I actually am interested in the 2nd case, the first case was a bit misphrased by me.

So, you kinda compare if the sum of the items at all is the same sum of the items where the condition matches, right?

I also already thought about that but couldn't wrap my head around it really... So, thanks!

Comment: do you maybe have some documentation reference for the ``sum(property = 'shipsFree')`` Syntax? It returns the sum of records matching the condition, I assume? And, regarding the count(*), wouldn't that count all records, i.e. the order ones? Shouldn't that be rather count(oi.orderId)?

Comment: Boolean comparisons like `column='whatever'` return `true` or `false` (`1` or `0`), so yes it returns the sum of records matching the condition. The `count(*)` counts all records per group, the only difference between `count(*)` and `count(oi.orderId)` would be, that `count(*)` returns the number of rows for this group and `count(oi.orderId)` would return the number of rows for this group where `orderId is not null`. I assume you have no order without orderItem? Then it makes no difference.

Comment: great, thank you; do you still have a source for the expression types which are possible in SUM()? I think there's a bug in Doctrine ORM, and to proof this, I would like to see a reference or so... thanks!

Comment: Something like this? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html

Comment: I don't think there's documentation about it. It's just a given fact. I know of no other DBMS where this is not possible. In fact, I don't think this is handled otherwise anywhere in computer science. Comparision -> true or false -> 1 or 0 ...that's how computers work, you know?

Comment: it's a lot more magic going on than just "being boolean". Following your argumentation, that would mean "SUM expects a boolean expression" which is just not correct. It might contain a field name, if so, each affected field's value will be SUM'd; and it can contain a boolean expression, if so, only these where it's TRUE are affected. Totally different story.

And »I don't think there's documentation about it. It's just a given fact.« is a bit weird explanation somehow...

Comment: You got me wrong. Of course it doesn't expect a boolean expression. But name only one area in the field of computers where a boolean expression does not return 1 or 0. That's my point. Maybe you should just create a question here on SO about your possible bug and work it out from there.